# copy files of multiple folders and rename them with cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command, directory, batch-rename

i have list of folders

files in all the folder are named in the same way

I want copying them in one folder without losing the order (folder 01(file01-02...) to folder 10)

I didn't find the way to do it with cmd or another way because I want to do it without any software just with windows

Comment: Have you try **xcopy** command ? 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289483/fr

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "startfolder=c:\data"
SET "targetfolder=x:\data"
for /d /r "%startfolder%" %%a in (*) do (
    SET "fname=%%~a"
    SET "fname=!fname:%startfolder%=!"
    ECHO MD "%targetfolder%!fname!\%%~nxa" 2>nul
    for %%b in ("%%~fa\*") do ECHO COPY "%%~fb" "%targetfolder%!fname!\%%~nb-new name%%~xb"
)
```

Look at the output and remove the word `echo`before `MD`and `COPY` if it looks good.

Comment: Please clarify how to set-up the code because I am a total beginner in coding and I just learned how to say hello in cmd

Comment: The code should make a copy of the source folder tree at the destination path below the start folder's level.